# Add additional functions file instead of functions.php

Tags: php

I was wondering if i could have more than one functions file in wordpress and how do I call these actions in for example a registration form?

Thanks.

EDIT
[image: form posting to registerprocess.php]

This the process file im trying to post to that has the code that connects to db and adds new user to db.  however this isnt working.do i need to include anything at the top of the page

Comment: The relative path here won't be relative to the template file when it gets included in something else, so that isn't going to work. You could switch that to be an absolute path to your registerProcess.php instead, but then you're calling a non-WP PHP file: it might be better to handle the post some other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can include multiple files in your `functions.php`. I do this to keep things organized. All my functions are in a `functions` subfolder, so my `functions.php` file just looks like this:

```
require get_template_directory() . '/functions/function-1.php';
require get_template_directory() . '/functions/function-2.php';
require get_template_directory() . '/functions/function-3.php';
```

If you have functions you only want called on certain pages, for example, you can do this:

```
if ( is_page( 'registration-form' ) ) :
    require get_template_directory() . '/functions/registration.php';
endif;
```

Comment: the have a form posting to registerprocess.php but it doesnt seem to be posting to the process here. Please see edit

Comment: See what @rup replied to your original post. I don't think you have any kind of WordPress issue, just a general issue with your PHP. Your question might be better suited for Stack Overflow.